# custom android view in nativescript using typescript

Tags: android, nativescript

I want to display a native android UI component (like a button or an canvas) in my nativescript app using typescript. As an example I want to extend an android button with following typescript code:

```
//custom.js
export class NativeComponent extends android.widget.Button{
  constructor(context){
      super(context);
      this.setText("test");
  }
}
```

and then I tried to load it in my xml view:

```
Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded">
  <StackLayout>
    <Label text="Tap the button" class="title"/>
    <Button text="TAP" tap="{{ tapAction }}" />
    <Label text="{{ message }}" class="message" textWrap="true"/>
    <custom:NativeComponent />
  </StackLayout>  
</Page>
```

... but this always crashes. The docs on this are very poor / I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?@Finkes

Answer (score 3):

In order for you to use the custom control you must add an XML Namespace so the framework knows from where to load the files. So your XML should look like:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" xmlns:custom="./path/to/custom.js" loaded="pageLoaded">
  <StackLayout>
    <Label text="Tap the button" class="title"/>
    <Button text="TAP" tap="{{ tapAction }}" />
    <Label text="{{ message }}" class="message" textWrap="true"/>
    <custom:NativeComponent />
  </StackLayout>  
</Page>
```

Also the JS code must follow some specific structure such as that you must have a public function `_createUI()` for android where you should place the native component creation. For iOS this is done in the constructor. Take a look at https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/ui-plugin.html for more details.